# Why does np.ma.median work for only certain sizes of nan matrices and give the MaskError('Cannot alter the masked element.') for other sizes

Tags: python, numpy, median, masked-array

I am trying to build a code that can be given an matrix of nans and not break. I wrote a simplified version here that recreates the problem. I am using numpy version 1.23.5

Basically the code takes a grid of nans and creates a annulus mask to apply to the grid and then take the median of what ever is in the annulus. This code does not produce the error as is.

```
from math import floor
from scipy.signal import convolve
import numpy as np

in_radius = 10
out_radius = 31
box_size = 5

box=np.ones((box_size,box_size))
padding=floor(box_size/2)

y,x=np.ogrid[-1*out_radius:out_radius+1,-1*out_radius:out_radius+1]
grid_mask=np.logical_or(x**2+y**2<in_radius**2,x**2+y**2>out_radius**2)

grid = np.empty((67,67),)
grid[:] = np.nan

smoothed=convolve(grid,box,method='direct',mode='valid') / 2

noisepix=np.ma.masked_array(smoothed,grid_mask)
median_signal = np.ma.median(noisepix)
```

The last line will produce a nan, which is fine.

However if I change out_radius to anything smaller than 28, `numpy` is unable to perform the calculation of the median. Here is the code that produces the error:

```
in_radius = 10
out_radius = 28
box_size = 5

box=np.ones((box_size,box_size))
padding=floor(box_size/2)

y,x=np.ogrid[-1*out_radius:out_radius+1,-1*out_radius:out_radius+1]
grid_mask=np.logical_or(x**2+y**2<in_radius**2,x**2+y**2>out_radius**2)

grid = np.empty((61,61),)
grid[:] = np.nan

smoothed=convolve(grid,box,method='direct',mode='valid') / 2

noisepix=np.ma.masked_array(smoothed,grid_mask)
median_signal = np.ma.median(noisepix)
```

The full error message is:

```
MaskError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/89/zgv9nv5563n89pzs55bv6mzm0000gq/T/ipykernel_17229/2791888929.py in <module>
     21 
     22 noisepix=np.ma.masked_array(smoothed,grid_mask)
---> 23 median_signal = np.ma.median(noisepix)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.py in median(a, axis, out, overwrite_input, keepdims)
    733             return m
    734 
--> 735     r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_median, axis=axis, out=out,
    736                     overwrite_input=overwrite_input)
    737     if keepdims:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _ureduce(a, func, **kwargs)
   3723         keepdim = (1,) * a.ndim
   3724 
-> 3725     r = func(a, **kwargs)
   3726     return r, keepdim
   3727 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.py in _median(a, axis, out, overwrite_input)
    779             if not odd:
    780                 s = np.true_divide(s, 2., casting='safe', out=out)
--> 781             s = np.lib.utils._median_nancheck(asorted, s, axis)
    782         else:
    783             s = mid.mean(out=out)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py in _median_nancheck(data, result, axis)
   1052             return data.dtype.type(np.nan)
   1053 
-> 1054         result[n] = np.nan
   1055     return result
   1056 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py in __setitem__(self, indx, value)
   3344         """
   3345         if self is masked:
-> 3346             raise MaskError('Cannot alter the masked element.')
   3347         _data = self._data
   3348         _mask = self._mask

MaskError: Cannot alter the masked element.
```

I am trying to understand why this is happening for one size of outer radius and not the other.

I know that I can work around this by replacing the array of nans with zeros or something and just compensating for it. I am more after why this is happening in some case and not in others

Comment: Do you realize that both cases are entirely masked with `nan` data values?  Does `median` in such a case make sense?  Without `axis` median works on the `ravel`, flat, array.  The 28 case works if I specify an axis.

Comment: The error occurs deep in the `ma` code.  Exactly why would require studying that code in some detail.  It's not your fault, except that you are asking for the median of a totally masked array.  `ma` is not heavily used, so I'm not surprised that some 'edge' case like this could be buggy.